# Communicate with subprocess Python REPL

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I subprocess and communicate/interact with the python repl?

I can make a fake REPL and communicate with it like so

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-u", "fakerepl.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("foo\n")
print process.stdout.readline().strip()
process.stdin.write("bar\n")
print process.stdout.readline().strip()
process.communicate('exit')
```

I can communicate with cat like so.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write('a')
process.stdin.write('b\n')
process.stdin.flush()
print process.stdout.readline()
process.stdin.write('c\n')
process.stdin.flush()
print process.stdout.readline()
```

But if I want to use the real python repl it hangs when trying to read the stdout.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-u"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("foo=2\n")
process.stdin.write("bar=3\n")
process.stdin.write("print foo+bar\n")
print process.stdout.readline()
process.stdin.write("baz=4\n")
process.stdin.write("print foo+bar+baz\n")
print process.stdout.readline()
```